# Open all files when user right clicks and selects "Open With"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application written in WPF/C# that can take multiple files as command line arguments.  When I run it from the command line with multiple files it opens all of them.  When I select multiple files in an explorer window and drag them to the applications icon it opens all of them.  But if I select multiple files in explorer and right click, select Open With, and then select my application it only opens the last one.  Is there a way to tell Windows that my application can handle more than one file?  I've noticed that some programs seem to work that way while others do not.

Answer (score 1):

The shell actually tries to start a separate instance of your application for *each* file selected.  Your app will need to (a) ensure that only the first instance actually shows its UI, and (b) do some inter-process communication to pass the files from the later instances to the first instance.  You might already be doing (a), but not (b), which would explain why you only see one file get opened.  See the second question (the part about "Single-Instance Apps") on [Stephen Toub's post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163741.aspx) about this.  You also may want to read about [Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648774.aspx), which is a common way to pass information between instances of an application.

Comment: If you're doing (a) (single instance app), how do you know whether instances 2 and 3 are actually starting or not (and thus passing information to the first instance)?

Comment: My test application did not do (a).

Comment: In that case choosing "Open with..." should start multiple instances of your application, one instance for each file selected.  If this isn't what's happening, there might be some hidden single-instace stuff hiding somewhere in your application initialization code.  (I don't think that's typical for standard WPF apps, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Thats a problem with windows explorer, only operating on the last file selected. Maybe this might help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/1d2e6a3b-6abb-4be9-82ac-447ecdbce201

Comment: I was ready to accept that, but if you select multiple Word documents and right click "Open With" Word it opens all of them.  I assume there's a special registry entry that makes Windows open multiple files this way.