# Handle multiple files with one instance of the program

Tags: c#, console-application

Basically the problem is that I'am trying to open files with the program I made by right clicking on the file and open with... It works fine for a single file but when I try to open multiple files at the same time it starts an instance of the program for each individual file.
Finally, What I'am trying to get to is a way of changing this behavior in order to make one instance of the program handle all files.
Thanks,

Comment: If you want to post your code it might be easier to figure this out.

Comment: It sounds like you are just using the Windows shell to open the files and that will, indeed, start a separate instance of the file handler for each file.

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if there is already an instance of the program running before you initialize the window then send the file path to the open program or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

You won't like the answer as it gets complex but it is already answered here...
[Open all files when user right clicks and selects "Open With"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158312/open-all-files-when-user-right-clicks-and-selects-open-with)